# Passing value from Partial view to Layout view in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How can I pass a value from partial view to _layout page ? I have tried to pass the value through ViewBag. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by passing a value *from a view*?  Shouldn't the *controller* be passing values *to* the views?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @David, 

I have a _loginpartial view with the following line.

 @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Location // Location is a custom column in AspNetUsers table.

I want to hide/show some links in Layout page based on user location. 
So instead of retrieving the user location in Layout page again, I was thinking of saving this value to a variable in _loginpartial and access it in  Layout page.

Comment: Fetch the value in the controller and store it in something like `ViewBag` or `ViewData`.  Then it'll be available to any component of the resulting constructed view.  Views shouldn't be *fetching* data, they should be supplied the data they need by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't recommend the pattern described in the question, you could store data in the `HttpContext.Items` dictionary and it should be available everywhere. The only question is order of execution, which I think is fine in this scenario.

The reason I don't recommend this is that the responsibilities of components seem a bit unusual here: I find it odd for a layout page to expect a partial view to set some data. It really ought to be done in a controller or filter.